# Angular radio button validation with an ng- repeat

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-validation

I'm running into an interesting Angular validation issue.  I need to make sure that radio buttons are selected (they might not have a  default value when loaded).  The values for the radio buttons are iterated over from an array using `ng-repeat`.  This whole thing also happens inside another `ng-repeat` for a list of users.

The issue is that I have to set a unique/dynamic `name` attribute on *each group* of related radio buttons, otherwise selecting one will unselect others in a different row. The validation in based on the `name` attribute and I cannot seem to find a way to use this unique/dynamic name in the needed `ng-class` and `ng-show` expressions.

This is waht is not working:
`ng-show="userFormRow.service-{{$index}}.$invalid"`

Here's a sample of the code in context:

```
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="u in users"
          ng-form="userFormRow">
        <td>
          <!-- THIS is having an issue determining the name of this form item since I need to generate a dynamic one here-->
          <div class="form-group"
               ng-class="{'has-error': userFormRow.service-{{$index}}.$invalid }">
            <label class="control-label center-block">Service</label>
            <div class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="o in serviceOptions">
              <label>
                <!-- HERE is where I define the unique name attribute based on the index of the table repeater -->
                <input type="radio"
                       name="service-{{$parent.$index}}"
                       value="{{::o}}"
                       ng-model="u.Service"
                       ng-required="!u.Service"> {{::o}}
              </label>
            </div>

            <!-- THIS is having an issue determining the name of this form item since I need to generate a dynamic one here-->
            <p class="help-block" ng-show="userFormRow.service-{{$index}}.$invalid">A service must be selected!</p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And here is a full code example.http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/eNoGLJ?editors=101   Check the console for errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access variable object property:

```
ng-show="userFormRow['service-' + $index].$invalid"
```

and same with ngClass:

```
ng-class="{'has-error': userFormRow['service-' + $index].$invalid }"
```

**Demo**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVbYpG?editors=100